# Open Layer basic example doesn't works

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

code:

```
<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("open_map");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 )
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
            map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
          );

    var zoom=16;

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);

    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));

    map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
  </script>
<div id="open_map" style="width:100%"></div>
```

i used the official site example, but it doesn't works for me, it doesn't shows any map in browser.

I have no errors in console, strange ... any idea?

EDITED

```
<div id="open_map" style="width:100%;height:300px;position:relative;"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("open_map");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 )
          .transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
            map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
          );

    var zoom=16;

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
    map.addLayer(markers);

    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));

    map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
  </script>
```

moved script after the div element now i see :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that *Twitter Bootstrap* sets this property on the `img` tag:

```
img { max-width:100%; }
```

I imagine that you want to get work with Open Layers map without breaking the whole theme, so you can just override that directive for your map div.

Example: you map have a div with `class="map"`, so the css is:

```
.map img { max-width:none; }
```

Comment: This was EXTREMELY helpful, thank you. Polymaps, Leaflet, etc. are all not affected by this so if you're switching to OpenLayers, this is very easy to miss...And super frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

You have two mistakes:

1. DIV element must go **before** your javascript, or place map creation code in DOM ready event.
2. You must set a height to yout div element.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvWXV/).

Comment: good trick, but i'm having problems with layers check question updated please ;9

Comment: @dfsq can't visualize some layers i think, it returns blank at center side :/

Comment: Does the link to jsfiddle I provided give you this strange view? Looks good for me.

Comment: @dfsq nope, this is a css problem i think, i'm using bootstrap css ... really can't find what's happening :/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on browsers, you may want to try putting a `height` and if not working putting fix width to the map `div` like `width:400px;height:400px`.
I know its strange but I got the case on a map showing on IE and chrome but not FF.